# Why there is a need of pageContext in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, el

When we can access all the implicit variables  in JSP, why do we have *pageContext* ?

My assumption is the following: if we use EL expressions or JSTL, to access or set the attributes we need *pageContext*. Let me know whether I am right.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need it to access **non**-implicit variables. Does it now make sense?

---

**Update**: Sometimes would just like to access the getter methods of [`HttpServletRequest`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) and [`HttpSession`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) directly. In standard JSP, both are only available by `${pageContext}`. Here are some real world use examples:

---

Refreshing page when session times out:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="${pageContext.session.maxInactiveInterval}">
```

---

Passing session ID to an Applet (so that it can communicate with servlet in the same session):

```
<param name="jsessionid" value="${pageContext.session.id}">
```

---

Displaying some message only on first request of a session:

```
<c:if test="${pageContext.session['new']}">Welcome!</c:if>
```

*note that `new` has special treatment because it's a reserved keyword in EL, at least, since EL 2.2*

---

Displaying user IP:

```
Your IP is: ${pageContext.request.remoteAddr}
```

---

Making links domain-relative without hardcoding current context path:

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login">login</a>
```

---

Dynamically defining the `<base>` tag (with a bit help of [JSTL functions](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html) taglib):

```
<base href="${fn:replace(pageContext.request.requestURL, pageContext.request.requestURI, pageContext.request.contextPath)}/">
```

---

Etcetera. Peek around in the aforelinked `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpSession` javadoc to learn about all those getter methods. Some of them may be useful in JSP/EL as well.

Comment: as i have mentioned for el expression language u need pageContext.

Comment: You don't need it to access implicit objects or attributes. E.g. `${param.name}` (for `request.getParameter(name)`), `${cookie.name}` (for cookies whose `getName().equals(name)`), `${header.name}` (for `request.getHeader(name)`) or `${attributename}` (for `pageContext.findAttribute(attributename)`) is then sufficient. All implicit objects are listed [here](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/819-3669/bnaij?l=es&a=view). By the way, your English is pretty poor. After thinking once more, there's probably ambiguity in your original question. You really need to verify and clarify this.

Comment: thanks for the answer and the time you spent. yes my english is poor , i will try to improve,by asking questions here.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @BalusC's excellent answer, the PageContext that you are getting might not be limited to what you see in the specification.

For example, [Lucee](http://lucee.org/) is a JSP Servlet that adds many features to the interface and abstract classes.  By getting a reference to the PageContext you can gain access to a lot of information that is otherwise unavailable.

Answer (score -1):

All 11 implicit EL variables are defined as Map, except the pageContext variable.
pageContext variable provides convenient methods for accessing request/response/session attributes or forwarding the request.